# jQuery: Picking values from Select before/after current Drop-Down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope I can explain this well.  Note the attached image below.  Each  has a classname of "classtime" and contains a list of available schedules for a class.

As you can see in the "instructions" in the image, I need to validate that a user doesn't select classes on back-to-back days.  I'm not sure how to do this in jQuery; I'm fairly sure it can be done, and probably easily, but I don't know how.

So the plan is to act on the change() event of a given drop-down, and then look at the value of the select before and the select after, and if the value is not 0, complain to the user and reset the value of the current drop-down to 0.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Thinking seems backwards and you should be disabling them instead. Not very user friendly to offer them choices they can't use then complain at user for selecting them

Comment: Please show what you have tried so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

This is one way with disables.

```js
$('select').change(function(){
    var hasVal = $(this).val() != 0;
    var index = $('select').index(this);
    var total = $('select').length;

    //before select
   if((index-1) >= 0){
       var disableBefore = hasVal;
        // check incase 2 before has a value
        if(!disableBefore && ((index-2) > 0)){
            disableBefore = $('select:eq(' + (index-2) + ')').val() != 0;
        }
       $('select:eq(' + (index-1) + ')').prop('disabled', disableBefore);
   }
    
    //after select
    if((index+1) < total){
        var disableAfter = hasVal;
      // check incase 2 after has a value
        if(!disableAfter && ((index+2) < total)){
            disableAfter = $('select:eq(' + (index+2) + ')').val() != 0;
        }
        $('select:eq(' + (index+1) + ')').prop('disabled', disableAfter);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <select>
        <option value="0">a</option>
        <option value="1">aa</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select>
        <option value="0">b</option>
        <option value="1">bb</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select>
        <option value="0">c</option>
        <option value="1">cc</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select>
        <option value="0">d</option>
        <option value="1">dd</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select>
        <option value="0">e</option>
        <option value="1">ee</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select>
        <option value="0">f</option>
        <option value="1">ff</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select>
        <option value="0">g</option>
        <option value="1">gg</option>
    </select>
</div>
```